# Redirect few pages of website depending resolutions' devices

Tags: redirect, responsive-design

I need to make a redirect for a few pages of my website depending on resolution.
For example:
If I have 10 pages in my website and I wanna that the pages 3, 4 and 5 are redirected if an user visit it with desktop, what I have to do?
I have a particular structure's website and the target is redirect the users that navigate some pages by desktop, but allow to view this pages for the users that navigate with mobile devices (the pages are made specifically for this).
I know there are various method: script js or php, .htaccess, but I don't have much knowledge about.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you need to rethink your user interface. If a user accesses the site on a mobile and finds the content they need and forward that through to their desktop they will not be able to access the content.

Check out [Categorizr](http://www.brettjankord.com/2012/01/16/categorizr-a-modern-device-detection-script/) that helps categorize different web capable devices into 4 categories, desktop, tv, tablet, or mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will read soon.
My website has a good structure. The users on mobile can views the same content of desktop, only the type of view is different: in the desktop the various pages are inside a mega menu (similar), while on mobile devices they can read those content as normal pages.